# angularJS - how to export to PDF in UI-grid using button click?

Tags: angularjs

I'm using aware about "http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/206_exporting_data". However, I'd like to PDF export onclick of button rather grid-menu. any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
-Ashwath

Comment: There's another library that has to be added, the name escapes me. I think if you check your console errors after clicking the button it will say "xxx" not available or similar which will give you the name.

Comment: @tuckerjt07 - How to call grid export on click of button, can you please help me? I've my button <input type='button'.... /> I want show this button of the top left corner of the grid, 
<input type='button' .... />
<div ui-grid="gridOptions"  ui-grid-exporter class="grid"></div>
...

Comment: I'm by no means an expert on this, I just recently started using it. In the tutorials on their site they show how to include a menu button in the grid. From there they allow pdf export to be called. I would look at how that works and see if I could make the same call on my own if desired.

Comment: If you get anything please do share.. Thanks a lot!!